# Chromium Embedded Framework won't build or run

Tags: windows, chromium, chromium-embedded

I'm trying out the tutorial for Windows on the wikipage of CEF at https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/wiki/Tutorial.

However, the CEF builds for 32 bit and 64 bit won't build/run on Visual Studio 2010.

By the way, I'm running **Windows 7 (64 bit) and Visual Studio 2010**.

Here are the errors:

**32 bit Build**

```
- error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_MSC_VER': value '1800' doesn't match value '1600' in simple_app.obj
- (A THOUSAND LINES OF ERRORS)
- out\Debug\cefsimple.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 11 unresolved externals
```

**64 bit Build**

```
- out\Debug\obj\libcef_dll_wrapper\transfer_util.obj : fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'X86' conflicts with target machine type 'x64'
- LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'C:\Users\Benj\Desktop\Blueprint Gaming\Chromium Embedded Framework\64 Bit\cef_binary_3.1921.1661_windows64\out\Debug\lib\libcef_dll_wrapper.lib'
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I assume you are referring to either the cef_simple or the cef_client projects that come bundled with the libraries...

**Fix**

Set the macro value for CEF_ENABLE_SANDBOX to 0 in cef_simple.cpp and cefclient_win.cpp

**What's happening**

The error indicates that a library you are linking to is not compatible with simple_app.obj. In this case, this library (cef_sandbox.lib) is built with _MSC_VER 1800 (that's VS2013 beta, if I am not wrong) while your current environment is _MSC_VER 1600 (VS2010).

Had the same problem a couple days back - cheers!

Comment: The CEF_ENABLE_SANDBOX constant is now in `/cefsimple/cefsimple_win.cpp` and `/cefclient/cefclient_win.cpp`

Comment: Has the CEF team been alerted? Seems kind of bad that it fails to build out of the box.